# Fining the angular bounds of a triple integral function

Tags: calculus, integration

This problem requires the taking of a triple integral over a region. I believe it's most useful to convert to cylindrical coordinates, which I did. However, I could not find the theta bounds due to the seeming lack of information. Is there a better way to approach this, or how does one find the theta bounds for the triple integral in cylindrical coordinates?

Find the mass within the region described by:

[image]

If the density is given by:

[image]

I computed the altered bounds in cylindrical coordinates and found the z bounds and the r bounds. However, I'm not sure how to approach finding the theta bounds.

Comment: What did you get for the $z$ and $r$ bounds?

Comment: For z, I got 4-4rsin(theta)<=z<=4-r^2. For r, I got 2/sin(theta)<=r<=4sin(theta).